# including two jquery library in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to include two jquery library in same page.function name 'myfunction' is common for both selectbox and datepicker.datepicker function call uses .onload the page I called loaddata() function for pagination.It uses  .So I want to know how to include both the library in same page.

Now I'm using 1.4.3 library so onload and .rec select box works but not datepicker function.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The above library is for calling function via datepicker

```
  $rec="select * from recruiter where comp_id='$comp'";
               $rec1=mysql_query($rec);

               echo '<select class="rec" id="r" name="e_first_name" style="width:155px;" required onchange="myFunction(this.value);">';
               echo '<option value="" selected>Select Recruiter</option>';
               while($rfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($rec1))
               {
                 echo '<option value="'.$rfet["e_id"].'">'.$rfet["e_first_name"].'</option>';
               }
               echo '</select>';


              echo ' <input type="text" name="dob" style="width:155px;display:none;"  id="datepicker1" placeholder="Choose Date" onchange=myFunction("'.$rfet["e_id"].'"); size=18 maxlength=50>';
               echo '<select name="report" style="width:155px;" class="report" onchange=myFunction("'.$rfet["e_id"].'");>
               <option selected> Select Filter</option>
               <option value="datz">By Date</option>
               <option value="week">By week</option>
               <option value="month">By month</option>
               </select>';
 echo ' <input type="text" name="dob" style="width:155px;display:none;"  id="datepicker1" placeholder="Choose Date" onchange=myFunction("'.$rfet["e_id"].'"); size=18 maxlength=50>';
  function myFunction(e_id)
{  

  $("#pre").hide();

   var fdat= $("#datepicker1").val();
   var filt= $(".report").val();
   var c=$("#r").val();

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "query3.php",
        data: { action: c,filt: filt,fdat: fdat},
        error: function(msg) {

        },
        success: function(text) {

            $(".refresh").html(text);          
        }
    });

   }
```

Comment: nothing is clear from your query. Why you want to include two jquery files? For code I can see you have jqeury and jqeury UI included... Do u want to include jquery other version apart from 1.10.2? Question is confusing keep it simple.

Comment: I want to use 1.4.3 and 1.10.2 js library in same page.

Comment: then use jQuery.noConflict

Comment: how to use it in this page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: If it were me, I would find plugins that use the same version of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment you need to use jQuery.noConflict.

In below example, two version of jquery included

1. `jquery-1.10.3.min.js`
2. `jquery-1.11.3.min.js`

For `jquery-1.10.3.min.js` - `$` will be the alias ie. you will access using `$`. But after `jquery-1.11.3.min.js` and I mean just after we have included `jquery. noConflict(true)` that means now we have resolve the conflict and defined a custom alias as `$j`. Now you can access `jquery-1.11.3.min.js`with `$j` alias. Hope this clears.

For example,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $j = jQuery.noConflict(true); 

        $j(document).ready(function(e){     
            $j("#test").click(function(){
                 alert("hi");
            });             

        });

 </script> 

</head>
<body>
<button id="test" type="button">Say Hi</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> with $j = jQuery.noConflict(true); but var fdat= $("#datepicker1").val();
   var filt= $(".report").val();
   var c=$("#r").val(); are not passed to next page in .report select tag and datepicker

Comment: First, if you want to access 1.10.2 jquery then u need to use $j instead of $. Second, I see you are using protocol less url?Are you running app on server or local. If local I would suggest use http or https as required to load jquery. If this doesn't solve then you need to debug your code more

Comment: how you are passing this to next page? That's another query. I can't see that in you code block.

Comment: ya I want to pass value fetched using jquery to next page. on my second page this value is not passed,If use 1.4.3.js along with this